# Camel-Case to Sentence-Case in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code to convert a camel-case phrase to sentence-case. It works fine for almost all cases, but it can't handle acronyms.  How can this code be corrected to work with acronyms?

```
private static final Pattern UPPERCASE_LETTER = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]|[0-9]+)");

static String toSentenceCase(String camelCaseString) {
    return camelCaseString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
            + UPPERCASE_LETTER.matcher(camelCaseString.substring(1))
            .replaceAll(matchResult -> " " + (matchResult.group(1).toLowerCase()));
}
```

JUnit5 test:

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index}: Convert {0} to sentence case")
@CsvSource(value = {"testOfAcronymUSA:Test of acronym USA"}, delimiter = ':')
void shouldSentenceCaseAcronym(String input, String expected) {
    //TODO: currently fails
    assertEquals(expected, toSentenceCase(input));
}
```

Output:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :Test of acronym USA
Actual   :Test of acronym u s a
```

I thought to add `(?=[a-z])` to the end of the regex, but then it doesn't handle the spacing correctly.

I'm on Java 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your immediate issue you may use

```java
private static final Pattern UPPERCASE_LETTER = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{2,})|([A-Z]|[0-9]+)");
static String toSentenceCase(String camelCaseString) {
    return camelCaseString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
            + UPPERCASE_LETTER.matcher(camelCaseString.substring(1))
            .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1) != null ? " " + m.group(1) : " " + m.group(2).toLowerCase() );
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/H3p1PM).

**Details**

- `([A-Z]{2,})|([A-Z]|[0-9]+)` regex matches and captures into Group 1 two or more uppercase letters, or captures into Group 2 a single uppercase letter or 1+ digits
- `.replaceAll(m -> m.group(1) != null ? " " + m.group(1) : " " + m.group(2).toLowerCase() )` replaces with space + Group 1 if Group 1 matched, else with a space and Group 2 turned to lower case.

Answer (score 2):

Change the regex to `(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]+|[A-Z](?=[a-z])|[0-9]+` where

1. `(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]+` specifies [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `[a-z]`
2. `[A-Z](?=[a-z])` specifies positive lookahead for `[a-z]`

Note that you do not need any capturing group.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static final Pattern UPPERCASE_LETTER = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]+|[A-Z](?=[a-z])|[0-9]+");

    static String toSentenceCase(String camelCaseString) {
        return camelCaseString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + UPPERCASE_LETTER.matcher(camelCaseString.substring(1))
                .replaceAll(matchResult -> !matchResult.group().matches("[A-Z]{2,}")
                        ? " " + matchResult.group().toLowerCase()
                        : " " + matchResult.group());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toSentenceCase("camelCaseString"));
        System.out.println(toSentenceCase("USA"));
        System.out.println(toSentenceCase("camelCaseStringUSA"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Camel case string
USA
Camel case string USA
```

Comment: Arvind, I thought to use the same thing (as posted in my question), but the unit test produces `Test of acronymUSA`.  It lacks the space before the acronym.  Run your main with `testOfAcronymUSA`

Comment: @vphilipnyc - I've updated my answer to meet this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Close, but USA would need to be capitalized to pass the unit test

Comment: @vphilipnyc - I've posted another update. I hope it meets your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue. Note that I'm getting late to go to bed; so, I will respond to your comment tomorrow.

Comment: I plan to go with the code presented in Wiktor's comment. Similar concept using `{2,}` to what you have in your answer.  Thank you!